# Hi CPU on tomcat8 irrespective of war deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, cpu-usage, tomcat8

I have started experiencing a strange issue with my tomcat8 server. I use it to exclusively run two applications - libresonic (a music streaming app) and guacamole (remote desktop gateway)

I am experiencing the tomcat process taking 100% of available CPU after the server has been running for a few hours with either application deployed. In order to troubleshoot I have done the following:

1. Spun up a vanilla Debian 8.6 Virtual Machine using KVM and installed:

   - Tomcat8
   - jdk-8 - 1.8.0_111
2. If I leave the tomcat instance running with no applications deployed the server and CPU usage remain inactive
3. If I deploy one of the applications (it doesn't matter which one), after a few hours the CPU usage climbs to 100%. Killing and restarting the tomcat server causes the CPU usage to drop, and then climb back to 100% after a few hours

Note that memory usage remains steady with plenty of free memory, so I don't believe this is a GC issue. Nothing related to memory is reported in the logs.

Catalina.out does not report any errors

I have taken threaddumps during the period of high CPU when each application is deployed. Other than being able to identify the threads that are in runnable state and consuming CPU, I cannot establish the root cause or ideas to rectify/fix the issue.

Can someone help? Threaddumps are linked below

[Download threaddumps](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1462564/threaddumps.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's related to this case (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57544). I have actually the same symptoms with tomcat 8.0.14. What is your tomcat version?

Comment: 8.0.14 thanks for the link. Will wait for 9 it seems. I've switched to jetty in the meantime.